# Making smooth pipes from coordinates in script

Tags: modeling, python

I am trying to generate pipes from coordinates, adding diameter to the pipe and using bevel and smoothing to make it look good. I am working on a script to do it, but I cant seem to work it out.

I have this code now

```
obj_name = "myobj"
mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new(f"{obj_name}_data")
mesh_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(obj_name, mesh_data)

# We need to add the objects to the scene so we can see it. 
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(mesh_obj)

bm = bmesh.new()

vert_coords = [
    ( 1.0,  1.0, 0.0),
    ( 1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    ( 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
    ]        
    
for coord in vert_coords:
    bm.verts.new(coord)

bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

bm.edges.new([bm.verts[0], bm.verts[1]])
bm.edges.new([bm.verts[1], bm.verts[2]])
bm.edges.new([bm.verts[2], bm.verts[3]])

bm.to_mesh(mesh_data)
mesh_data.update()

# Check if the object exists in the scene
if obj_name in bpy.data.objects:
    # Select the object
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj_name]
    bpy.data.objects[obj_name].select_set(True)
    # Switch to Edit mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
else:
    print(f"Object named '{obj_name}' not found in the scene.")

# bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset=0.130244, offset_pct=0, affect='VERTICES')
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj_name]
bpy.data.objects[obj_name].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset=0.5, offset_pct=0, segments=4, affect='VERTICES')
bm.free()
```

I am strugling switching to edit mode, selecting the object and applying the bevel.
Then I want to convert to curve and alter the geometry.

Does anyone have a simple script that does this.
I am able to follow manual steps looking at videos, but no solution in my code.

Thanx
Bernt

Comment: Welcome, add *bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')* before *bpy.ops.mesh.bevel*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ***bmesh.ops.bevel*** instead of *bpy.ops.mesh.bevel* eliminates the need to switch to Edit mode.

```
import bpy, bmesh

obj_name = "myobj"
mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new(f"{obj_name}_data")
mesh_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(obj_name, mesh_data)

# We need to add the objects to the scene so we can see it. 
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(mesh_obj)

bm = bmesh.new()

vert_coords = [
    ( 1.0,  1.0, 0.0),
    ( 1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    ( 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
    ]        
    
for coord in vert_coords:
    bm.verts.new(coord)

bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

bm.edges.new([bm.verts[0], bm.verts[1]])
bm.edges.new([bm.verts[1], bm.verts[2]])
bm.edges.new([bm.verts[2], bm.verts[3]])

bmesh.ops.bevel(bm, geom=bm.verts[:]+bm.edges[:], offset=0.5, segments=4, profile=0.5, affect='VERTICES')

bm.to_mesh(mesh_data)
mesh_data.update()
bm.free()

'''
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
mesh_obj.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = mesh_obj
'''
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = mesh_obj
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
mesh_obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='CURVE')
```

**Edit**:
bpy.ops.object.mode_set fails if active object is None. In other words

```
>>> bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = None
>>> bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender\blender-4.0.0-windows-x64\4.0\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 109, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() Context missing active object
```

To avoid this, I decided to move to object mode using context.view_laye.

Comment: Thank you very much tetii. For some reason the bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') doesnt work. When I remove that line everything runs fine. I googled around on it, and found some people also having trouble with that. I dont know why.

Comment: @Bernt. Thank you for reporting the problem. I found that *bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')* cannot be executed when *bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active==None*. I'll fix it later.